# freemarker, parse values from template

Tags: java, templates, freemarker

Is it possible to make next using freemarker?

e.g. in template i specify some values (i hope my syntax isn't misleading):

```
<td>${{<img src="[1234:thumb]" /><img src="[3456:thumb]" />}?{images are missing}}</td>
```

Idea is that, if application can make value, then new value used in template, if can't - default value is used. Main point is that i need values ("1234:thumb") from template to create correct output.

Here application get "1234:thumb" and "3456:thumb" from template and create images based on these value. If imagecreation was successful (both images), path to images written back to output:

```
<td><img src="images/1234.jpg" /><img src="images/3456.jpg" /></td>
```

If either of images wasn't created, default value ("images are missing") written to output:

```
<td>images are missing</td>
```

So 2 questions:

1. is it possible to store that values in template and parse them?
2. what is correct way to output default value (if/else in template or in application)?

Comment: I would say that logic shouldn't be in the template.

Comment: @andy-pryor, yes, you are right, that it is wrong place for this logic. I done it in different way.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have two variables for your two images: thumb1234 and thumb3456.

You can test whether these variables are set using the "??" operator.

```
<#if thumb1234?? && thumb3456??>
    <td><img src="${thumb1234}" /><img src="${thumb3456}" /></td>
<#else>
    <td>images are missing</td>
</#if>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but it is not what i asked.